# How to bundle many dylibs (while keeping directory structure) in a macOS .app executable with a nuget .targets file?

Tags: xamarin, nuget, dllimport, dylib, xamarin.mac

I'm currently trying to package ~350 native C dylibs in a single nuget for macOS. The .targets file should bundle the dylibs in the final mac .app while maintaining a specific folder architecture of those dylibs.

If that's relevant, most of the dylibs are `Mach-0 64-bit bundle x86_64` which is why I believe `NativeReference` does not work. Is that a correct assumption?

The couple ones I need to load with the Objc runtime from C# for P/Invoke are `Mach-0 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64` (they will handle the bundle ones, and expect them to be in a specific relative location).

My attempt is here https://github.com/mfkl/libvlc-nuget/pull/5/files. Feel free to ignore the MSBuild plugin [cherry-picking work](https://github.com/mfkl/libvlc-nuget/blob/master/cherry-picking.md).

I cannot get all the dylibs to be *inside* the mac .app bundle and create folders in there.

Edit: Adding more information.

Tried `NativeReference`, `Content`, `EmbeddedResource` and `BundleResource`. The files either don't get included or end up in `bin/debug` next to the .app bundle, which correct me if I'm wrong, is not what you want when shipping a library. Unsure what to use or if the paths are wrong, but feedback from MSBuild in VS seems to be non existent regarding this.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "I cannot get the dylibs to be inside the mac .app bundle."? What is the current behavior now?

Comment: Just did so. Let me know if that's enough info

Answer (score 0):

Without debugging your build, it is hard to tell (since there is no build log attached that I see), but my bet is that you are adding NativeReference items to your project too late for them to be seen by mmp.

It is in theory possible to dynamically generate project NativeReference for processing by your Xamarin.Mac project, but it needs to happen *before* `_CompileToNative`, where we process those items. It might even need to happen before `CoreCompile`, I'm not certain.

But yes, in general you want to use NativeReference to have your items added to the final bundle. Depending on your libraries, install_name_tool games might have to be added to fix up relative dependency paths. MMP (the packaging tool) knows how to handle some of those if you use NativeReference's.

If you need to do post-build tweaks, you can use the route shown in the MSBuild sample (CreateAppBundleDependsOn). https://github.com/xamarin/mac-samples/blob/master/UseMSBuildToCopyFilesToBundleExample/UseMSBuildToCopyFilesToBundleExample/CustomBuildActions.targets

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. I managed to bundle the dylibs but still cannot load them. Hitting `could not find the runtime library libxammac.dylib` when making a p/invoke call.